# GWT - Serialize as superclass

Tags: gwt, serialization

I am trying to send a `Game` object from the server to the client in GWT. This Game object simply contains a list of `Player`:

```
public class Game implements Serializable {
    private List<Player> players;
}
```

A `Player` is a simple Pojo that contains the player's state, like the name, remaining life, etc.

```
public class Player implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private int numberOfGamesPlayed;
    private double hp, initialHp;
}
```

However, the game can also contain a `CpuPlayer`, that is a `Player` with additional Artificial Intelligence logic

```
public class CpuPlayer extends Player {
    private PlayerIntelligence intelligence; // Not serializable
}
```

Both the `Game` and `Player` objects are in my "shared" package, and should be used on server and client side.

However, the `CpuPlayer` contains many internal processing data, and is purely server-side. It is therefore not included in GWT serialization whitelist.

What I would like to do is to send the `CpuPlayer` as a `Player` to the client, i.e. mask all the subclass specificities during the serialization.

Is this approach sound? Is there a way to do that? I looked at custom serialization, but it didn't seem to work that way (I would need to serialize all the fields one by one).

Thanks for your help,
Sébastien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of would be to use a library like [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) to copy everything you need from the CpuPlayer into the Player. This is as simple as calling

```java
Player player = new DozerBeanMapper().map(cpuPlayer, Player.class);
```

(the performance overhead for copying is probably negligible (sub-milliseconds)).

Another approach could be using RequestFactory instead of GWT-RPC, which is designed to transfer only a part of the server side object to the client (ideal for cases like yours, where you cannot send the entire internal data to the client).

Comment: I went with your first mapping approach. It was much easier to simply add a filter before sending the result than changing the way my service was called.