# How to write a GWT CustomSerializer for XMLGregorianCalendar?

Tags: java, gwt, serialization

I need a solution for serializing the XMLGregorianCalendar through RPC.

I wrote a custom serializer for the XMLGregorianCalendar object so far, but the object to be serialized is the internal Xerxes implementation of the Calendar type (com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl).

So my serializer fails miserably because it is not used.

Writing a serializer for the internal object is not a good idea and produces warnings in eclipse, that the class is restricted (Access restriction: The type XMLGregorianCalendarImpl is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\java\jre\lib\rt.jar).

Did anyone ever manage to use this XMLGC with GWT successfully on the client side?
Can I replace the XMLGC class in gwt.xml possibly and replace it by something different?

Any help appreciated!

UPDATE:

Wanted to tell you what did not work so far:

- Added a Supersource path and replaced the XMLGC class with a much simpler class, only carrying the data elements.
- Added a custom serializer class for XMLGC to serialize XMLGC from/to the lightweight supersource class.
- The approach failed at runtime, as the object beeing transported is not a XMLGC, but a com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl, that is in a sealed package in the rt.jar.
- The approach to repeat the same steps for the XMLGCImpl failed for me, maybe because I am too stupid, maybe because the sealed package is hindering the process.

Can someone confirm, that this approach should be working or is the approach doomed because of the Impl class? Maybe there is a GWT annotation/configuration, where I could tell the serializer to accept the XMLGC serializer for any extension of XMLGC?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the RPC serialization. The problem is that `XMLGregorianCalendar` is not [emulated](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html), so it cannot be used on the client-side. Serializing it through RPC wouldn't help.

There is an [issue to add better javax.time support to GWT](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=603), but it's very complicated to emulate these date & time APIs, so it's still work in progress.

For now, as a workaround, I would advise using a `java.util.Date` in your DTO, with a mapping layer on the server-side to translate your "server POJO" containing XMLGregorianCalendar into a "GWT DTO" containing a Date.

Also, while googling, I found [this class](http://enunciate.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/enunciate/modules/gwt/XMLGregorianCalendarGWTMapper.html), which is part of the [Enunciate](http://enunciate.codehaus.org/) library. It might possibly be useful for the XMLGregorianCalendar <--> Date mapping on the server-side.

Comment: Yes, I know it is not available. I am already above that step :-) I actually looking for a way to use the Gregorian Calendar on the client, by replacing the implementation by my own. I think, I did already a good job writing the serializer, and actually, I can compile my code. But now, during runtime, the XMLGC is actually another object. Can I advise the serializer to replace that object by something different? As you can see, the Xerces package is sealed, so I cannot do anything with this class in terms of overwriting. For now, I already do copy to DTO but duplicating that layer is unwanted.

Comment: Many people already tried using GregorianCalendar / XMLGregorianCalendar / DateTime on the client, and a few open source projects were created (e.g. gwt-joda-time), as well as feature requests ( https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=603 ). But these projects are no longer active, and the feature hasn't been added to GWT yet, because emulating date-time code in GWT is harder than it seems. That's why I think reimplementing GregorianCalendar in GWT might be complex. Couldn't you replace the XMLGregorianCalendar in your DTO with a Date?

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717811/gwt-serialize-as-superclass

Comment: Changing the XML layer is too much. I will look into the Dozer utility. For now, we fall back to "semi-generated" delegate DTOs that will wrap the XMLGC fields with Strings. Downside is, that I have to create a new object for each and every XMLGC containing object and cannot simply copy an object graph from XML over RPC to the client. As we only need to read the values inside the XMLGC on the client, we hoped to be able to replace the XMLGC in client code basically with a wrapper around a string. But this seems not to be the case. I leave the question as unanswered and upvote your answer, Thx!